# Check Facebook login status without an app?

Tags: facebook, authentication, status

Is there a way to check whether a user (of my webpage) is logged-in to Facebook, without involving a Facebook app (or rather without actually logging into an app)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method of FB JS API: [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

Comment: If I understand correctly: **(1)** I can use the FB.getLoginStatus to check the Facebook login status; **(2)** I still need an app; **(3)** I don't have to login the user to that app....... am I right?